# Connection to peripheral after PIN is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Another BLE peripheral issue. Hope that this one is solvable. The situation is following:

1. I connect and pair to the peripheral device and it doesn’t have PIN code at the start.
2. I set PIN through my app and the new PIN is set in the peripheral.
3. Finally the problem: iPhone doesn’t recognize the bluetooth peripheral device anymore and now the only way for me seems to be to go to iPhone settings and then click to forget this BLE device. After it is forgotten, I can go back to our application and pair from new with our new pairing PIN code.

Question - is there any way to NOT go to settings and forget. This is clumsy step to do that, so I am looking for some alternatives. Maybe somehow could request to input new PIN after iPhone understands that PIN is not the same as the paired one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got answer for this from bluetooth manufacturer: "There is no other way [only through iPhone settings]. Changing a PIN is not something that the average user will do very often, usually it happens only after a firmware update or major configuration change."

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete bonding information on BLE device side (it's stored on both sides - on phone and device). On esp32 it can be done [in this way](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/b1fa1ba61745df07dab62ef91c28f82f91158751/examples/bluetooth/gatt_security_server/main/example_ble_sec_gatts_demo.c#L246).